# How to copy data (datatype BLOB) into another table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, blob

I want to copy data from blob to another table in the same data type blob but it turns to

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '???q}??I=|(T???>?????77j{{???~?>O??i?:??Ѹ>??~ݻw??_????㷈???Q/?8l>? XW?c' at line 1

As I discovered, the imageDesign cannot be transferred because of the data are too long because if the data is only 1.7KiB, it can be transferred. Please help me for my fyp project

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM cart where userID = '$user_id'";  
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);  
    $countOrd =  mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
    {  
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
         {
             $productQuantity = $row["productQuantity"];
             $productID = $row["productID"];
             $productSize = $row["productSize"];
             $productColour = $row["productColour"];
             $designType = $row["designType"];
             $readymadeID = $row["readymadeID"];
             $imageDesign = $row["imageDesign"];

    $add_query ="INSERT INTO orders(userID,productID,productSize,productColour,orderQuantity,designType,readymadeID,imageDesign,orderPayment,orderStatus,orderDate,orderTime) values ('$user_id','$productID','$productSize','$productColour','$productQuantity','$designType','$readymadeID','$imageDesign','$payment','Pending','$orderDate','$orderTime')";
    $delete_query="DELETE from cart where userID='$user_id'";
    $add_query_result=mysqli_query($con,$add_query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $delete_query_result=mysqli_query($con,$delete_query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    }}
```

Comment: A prepared statement will make your syntax less error prone. In may in fact be required for the blob part.

Comment: FYI: Your code has a glaring [SQL injection vulnerability](https://geekflare.com/sql-injection-prevention-php/). If you don't know what that is, please read about it, and fix your code accordingly, otherwise a hacker can easily steal all your data and destroy your database. As a side-effect, your BLOB will work too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Blob-Data will not work with dynamic-adhoc-sql (which is to be avoided at any cost anyway). A very good guide on working with blob-data (and the mandatory parameter-binding):
[MySQL & Blob](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql-blob/)